# Count number of true values in each row

Tags: php, html, mysql, optimization, phpmyadmin

I've created a MySQL database using PHPMyAdmin which stores data that a user on a webpage selects. Basically, the user can click buttons on the page, and when they are clicked, the corresponding column in the database changes from 0 to 1. However, I only want each user to be able to select up to 6 option.
For example:

<kbd>id</kbd><kbd>opt1</kbd><kbd>opt2</kbd><kbd>opt3</kbd><kbd>opt4</kbd><kbd>opt5</kbd><kbd>opt6</kbd><kbd>opt7</kbd><kbd>opt8</kbd><kbd>total</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>3</kbd>     

<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>6</kbd>     

<kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>0</kbd>     <kbd>1</kbd>

*'id' represents each individual user, 'opt#' is the options they chose, and 'total' is the number of options selected.*

The code I have used for this is

```
//$id is the id of the user that is logged in
$total=$row['total']; //Fetch data from column 'total' for logged in user
$choice=$_GET['opt']; //Set 'choice' variable to value submitted by button
$selected=$row[$choice]; //Fetch value of corresponding column

if ($total>= 6) {   
    echo "Too many selected";   
}
elseif (!$selected) {
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `choices` SET `$choice` = '1', `total` = total+1 WHERE `choices`.`id` = '$id'");
}
else {
    echo "You have already selected this";
};
```

This code works fine and prevents the database from updating when count equals 6, but I am worried that a user may be able to modify that value as select more options than they should, or there could simply be a problem when I add code to allow the user to deselect options.

**Is it possible to make the 'total' column automatically update by counting the number of 'opt#' columns which have a value of 1 rather than adding 1 every time a user selects another option?** I'd imagine that it would involve adding the values, but as I'm a beginner with PHP and MySQL, I'm not sure what code I would have to use to implement it.

Hopefully my question isn't too confusing (I will be happy to clarify anything). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MariaDB (the better MySQL) you can create a VIRTUAL COLUMN that hold the sum of the 6 fields. it updates automaticly and you can also put a index on it.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
     id INT NOT NULL,
     opt1 int DEFAULT '0',
     opt2 int DEFAULT '0',
     opt3 int DEFAULT '0',
     opt4 int DEFAULT '0',
     opt5 int DEFAULT '0',
     opt6 int DEFAULT '0',
     total INT AS (opt1+opt2+opt3+opt4+opt5+opt6) PERSISTENT);
```

see Manual: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bb]> CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ->      id INT NOT NULL,
    ->      opt1 int DEFAULT '0',
    ->      opt2 int DEFAULT '0',
    ->      opt3 int DEFAULT '0',
    ->      opt4 int DEFAULT '0',
    ->      opt5 int DEFAULT '0',
    ->      opt6 int DEFAULT '0',
    ->      total INT AS (opt1+opt2+opt3+opt4+opt5+opt6) PERSISTENT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.50 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> insert into table1 (opt3,opt4) VALUES (1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> insert into table1 (opt3) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> insert into table1 (opt1) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bb]> select * from table1;
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| id | opt1 | opt2 | opt3 | opt4 | opt5 | opt6 | total |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
|  0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |     2 |
|  0 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     1 |
|  0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     1 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

Comment: MySQL (5.7.6) also supports [generated columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). From 5.7.8  virtual columns can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the real problem/solution?  Ponder the following...

You publish your UI.  Pretty soon, a 'user' calls you to complain:  "I am clicking on a button but nothing is happening!".  First you stare at the code to see if something is broken.  Then you remember your "6" restriction and ask them if they have 6.  The user goes away either embarrassed or angry at the UI for not making it more obvious.

Then you realize you need a popup, or to have the "total=6" flash, or something else so that that complaint won't come in again.

In other words, start by making a friendly User Interface, and only then see what SQL is needed.

Once you have done that, you may decide to dispense with the 'total' column.